# Apply same JLabel in all GridLayout Spots?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I wanna make a grid with r rows and c columns. I made the grid layout, created a label that I wanna use in all of the grid position using a for, but I've been only been able to set the label on one grid spot. How do I do use it on all spots, and whatsit that I'm not doing?

```
public class Grid {
    private JFrame f;

    public Grid(String fname, int row, int column, int d) {
        f = new JFrame(fname);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(row,column));
        f.setSize(row*d,column*d);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addContent(row,column,d);
    }

    public void open() {
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addContent(int r, int c, int d) {
        JLabel label=new JLabel(" ");
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2);
        label.setBorder(border);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d,d));
        for(int i=0;i!=r+c; i++) {
            f.add(label);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Grid grid = new Grid("Test", 5, 4, 50);
         grid.open();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Can someone get me a code example of how should I generate the copies of the label?

Comment: a swing component can only have 1 parent, that is, can only be added at *one position* (every time it is added, it is first removed)

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, [edit] the question, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 1):

Any component can only belong to a single parent/container. Adding the same instance of `JLabel` to you container is simply removing it first from its current parent before adding it to it's new parent (all be it, the same parent).

You need to create multiple instances of the `JLabel`.

I would consider using some kind of factory pattern to reduce any potentially duplicated code

Comment: So i could use the i, convert to string, add the string to the label tag, and create label0, label1, label2...

Comment: You could use an array

Comment: Can you get me a code example of how should i generate the copies of the label?